# How to pass a POST request in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

How can I POST and DELETE requests using ReactJS?

My REST application is built in ASP.Net and Core 1.0.1 (API handling data).

Comment: React doesn't handle server communications, it's up to you to choose how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React was designed for MVC Views, and as such is AJAX/data agnostic.

I recommend a library made for simplifying ajax requests, like axios or fetch.js

https://github.github.io/fetch/

Flux might also interest you, as it's an architecture by facebook for implementing data in your frontend:

https://facebook.github.io/flux/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a promise based library like 'axios' to make async requests and chain the state change inside the promise then method